# Creating an App to distribute with my CV?

Tags: resume

I'm planning to apply for a technical apprenticeship, I'm thinking about creating an Android App to send to the employer. I'll be sending them a standard CV too.

Would this be professional, should I put the source on a platform like GitHub for them to look at?

Comment: Could someone give me an idea why this is getting downvoted? Seems a little counterproductive to downvote something without giving any sort of reasoning.

Comment: Just wanted to follow that up. If the downvotes are because this post somehow off topic or against the rules comment why or flag it, downvoting without saying anything really doesn't inform anyone and frankly is petty. As far as I know this is in fact on topic and a valid question, if I knew why this isn't a great would not have posted it. Just leaves a sour taste in the mouth.

Comment: Sounds like a creative method to me :). Perhaps people are downvoting it for it being too open-ended and opinion-based? I don't know; I had upvoted it :). And sorry for the bad taste :/. I've had the same experience before on these Stack Exchanges. But welcome still.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I see, that makes sense now. Thanks pal. ;)

Comment: I commend the creativity, but I wouldn't outright send them an .apk though. Adding your Github link to your CV is never a bad idea for a developer, in my opinion, and should suffice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is only going to work for a very small number of potential employers:

- most employers either use a recruiting agency, or an application portal like Seek, or simply want you to submit your application the same way as everyone else - through an online form or email. If you send anything outside their preferred stream, it's most likely going to be ignored.
- send how? Most people should be (and are) wary about apps from outside the Play Store, especially given they are an attack vector.
- finally, what will this app actually do? Will it provide anything more than a view of your resume?

The better thing to do is stick to the traditional resume, but refer to an app (or apps) you have created and put in the Play Store. Also, don't send source code out blindly - it will almost certainly not be read by anyone other than someone who would want to replicate your work. (of course, under GPL you have to make it available on request)

Comment: I wouldn't attach an apk (nobody with a brain would run it), but a link to a web page with the app (including source code) possibly in github would be followed by interested hiring managers.  I disagree that most employers use agencies and portals-  if you're targeting employers you're avoiding those things and going straight to internal recruiters and hiring managers.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't just attach an APK, I suspect few (if any) employers would look at it, and some may even get suspicious of a strange looking attachment and skip over your application entirely.

However, there's nothing wrong with putting a Github link on your CV - if you wish, you can add instructions and an easily accessible APK there.

The only other thing I'd bear in mind is that for anything other than a junior development position / internship, it might look a bit odd if you clearly just created the app for the sole purpose of adding to your CV and nothing else (unless it demonstrated something particularly cool or interesting.)

Answer (score -3):

I am doing exactly this. I want a way to share my most valuable private information on the Android platform while simultaneously demonstrating the power of encryption.

All string and image resources are encrypted and can only be decrypted when a employer request an access code.

It cannot easily be reversed engineered to view my confidential information.

Maybe its a glorified zip with password protection but now I can confidently share my cv and only grant access to legitimate requests.

The benefit is now the employer can easily contact me via the app while also keeping myself first in line for anyjob should they commit to install and decrypt my cv.

Comment: I am wondering if you got a job interview yet? If not, you may want to re-consider the way you send your CV.

Comment: must be a troll